# Newton-Raphson method for a vector function with root bracketing / root constraint?

Tags: numerical-methods, vectors, newton-raphson

With scalar functions it is easy to construct a mixed Newton-Raphson-bisection algorithm so that the solution always stays inside the given bounds in which it is bracketed. What if I have a vector function which I want to finds its roots (each root depending on the other roots), but I know that the true roots have the same sign as my initial guess, and that it *must* stay that way in every step of the iteration procedure in order that the solution doesn't become irretrievable. Can I use this information to ensure the convergence of my solution?

To be more clear, I have a vector $\pmb{f}$ of functions, which are all the same except evaluated at different positions. Each of these component functions depend on a root vector $\pmb{x}$ comprised of all the roots at these positions. Symbolically, $\pmb{f}(\pmb{x})$ looks like 
$$f_i(\pmb{x})=\int_{y_i-a}^{y_i}g(y^{\prime})x(y^{\prime})dy^{\prime}+h(y_i)$$
where $x=x(y)$ is a function of position. Equivalently (?), $\pmb{x}$ can be considered as a vector solution where each of the different discrete values $y$ takes gives a component $x_i=x(y_i)$.

Now I know this is an integral equation system, but mine is actually much more complex and I'd like to solve it with Newton-Raphson if possible. The problem is that with NR alone, the solution tends to wander off in a region where some of the roots change sign, and this makes sure the solution gets forever lost.

Just to make sure, the way I proceed using only Newton-Raphson to find the roots of a vector function $\pmb{f}(\pmb{x})$ is by computing 
$$dx_i(\pmb{x})=\frac{f_i(\pmb{x})}{f_i^{\prime}(\pmb{x})}$$
where
$$f_i^{\prime}(\pmb{x})=\frac{\partial f_i(x)}{\partial x}\Bigr|_{\pmb{x}}$$
where the boldface was dropped to show the differentiation is with respect to a variable, and then applying
$$\pmb{x}_{n+1}=\pmb{x}_n-\pmb{dx}_n$$
until convergence.

I tried to use some kind of bisection method (which I know doesn't work for multidimensional problems) but I can't seem to be able to bracket a root. I asked that ${x_1}_i={x_i}_0/10$ and ${x_2}_i={x_i}_0\times 10$, calculated $\pmb{f}_1=\pmb{f}(\pmb{x}_1)$, for example. But it doesn't seem to me that such method can be generalized for a vector function.

In a way, I guess I could try a multivariate Newton-Raphson method, but usually in these cases, the vector $\pmb{x}$ is a vector of distinct variables. In my case, it's a single variable but which depends on position, hence is numerically an array. Doing partial derivatives would mean doing a derivative of that variable only at a specific position, and since I have to integrate over all positions (see below for the form of the $f_i(\pmb{x})$), it would be pretty awkward I think. Or maybe I am mistaken and it has nothing to do with Newton-Raphson. At least I know the method I explained worked for a relatively simple case, as it gave the same result as another root-finding scheme.

Is there a way to solve such a problem? I guess that if I try to solve the integral equation problem I am not guaranteed that the solution won't change sign in the process either?

Comment: It's similar, but it's not a system of equation with multiple, distinct variables. The function which I am trying to find its roots is a vector; but each component is the same equation but at a different geometric point. And each root is a quantity at a different geometric point. Each of these component functions depend of the whole vector root. I'll update my post as it's not so clear on this. But from what I understand, in this case it doesn't make sense to use a multivariable Newton method?

Comment: updated. I also fixed an error regarding my function **f**

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing this kind of problems many years ago and my initial attempt w
has to adapt subroutine **rtsafe** of *Numerical Recipes* to $n$ dimensions. It revealed to not be good because one of the variables could force many bisection steps in order that all variables stay within bounds.

Finally, what I decided to do is to turn the problem into the minimization of the norm using bound constraints. We have so many good optimizers !

Just give a try and, please, let me know about your experience.

Comment: That's exactly what I tried to do! You mean minimizing $\pmb{f}\cdot\pmb{f}$ in the "traditionnal" way? I know that in *Numerical Recipes* (2nd edition) they incorporate this minimization with multivariate Newton-Raphson, warning that simply doing the minimization alone could be problematic. Is there a specific(s) method I should try in such a case? But since it's not a "true" multivariate Newton-Raphson problem and the functions and roots are closely related, the system may be better behaved?

Comment: Well, this has been my experience. Optimization with bound constraints is really the simplest. If your opimizer is not able to handle bound constraints (I doubt this could be the case), you could use a "simple" optimizer changing variable $$x_i=a_i+\frac{b_i-a_i}{1+e^{-y_i}}$$ The $y_i$ are unbounded but you could face many problems if one of the solutions is close to one of its bounds.

Comment: I must say I am not familiar with optimization algorithms. I can only find constrained maximization algorithms (save simulated annealing) in *Numerical Recipes*, is there any book or on-line resource you can recommend me on the subject?

Comment: What is your computing environment ? Which programming language are you using ? Have you access to subroutine libraries ? If yes, which ones ?

Comment: I work on a GNU/Linux system and I program in FORTRAN 77. I don't think I have any access to subroutine libraries.

Comment: Glad to know that ! I cannot work now but I shall be back within 12 hours fron now. I think I should have something for you. Don't dream too much. See you then very soon. May be, we could go to a chat room.

Comment: @SpearheadBT.Glad to know that ! I cannot work now but I shall be back within 12 hours fron now. I think I should have something for you. Don't dream too much. See you then very soon. May be, we could go to a chat room. Have a look here : http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt

Comment: http://mat.uc.pt/~zhang/software.html . **TOLMIN** (from the guru Prof. Powell) seems to be of interest. You can download it.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, it's very appreciated. I'll take a look at TOLMIN. But come to think of it, I need a self contained code, so I don't think I should use external librairies like NLopt. But thanks for that nonetheless, I'll keep it bookmarked in case I need it later.

Comment: I have one standalone code of mine.

Comment: I've read a bit more about standard (ie. without constraints) optimization algorithms. A lot seem to either need derivatives (which I don't think would work in my case) or to find optimal directions by first going into different directions represented by each dimension of the trial point. The problem with this, is that by changing only one of the values of the trial roots, I create a dip in my integral. Does your code include such thing? Because I'm starting to think my problem is not so fit for optimization.

Comment: I tried something with halving my Newton steps until the trial is no longer out of bounds (why haven't I thought about this earlier!), but it converges extremely slowly, if it converges at all. Also, I think there's some modifications I should do with regards to my problem to make it more manageable. I might have over-simplified it.

Comment: @SpearheadBT. I have one standalone Fortran subroutine which can be used for solving a set of N nonlinear equations in N variables inside fixed bounds. The derivatives can be given or numerically evaluated.  My e-mail address is in my profile.